# Ship Logs from One Azure Log Analytics Workspace to Another

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-automation, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

We are a Managed services provider and have around 30 tenants managed via Azure Lighthouse.

Each tenant has a Log Analytics Workspace that collects the Logs and Metrics for the resources hosted under that Tenant.

My question is can we ship data from Workspaces of All tenants to the Main Workspace that is on our tenant. This is mainly because we want to create Alert rules, which does not take multiple resources as source.

If there are better alternatives to achieve this, Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [Move a Log Analytics workspace to different subscription or resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/move-workspace) Microsoft document then you will find that it is very easy to move logs from one Log Analytics workspace to another in different subscription.

But if you try to move the logs from one tenant to another tenant then it becomes a bit difficult as a lot of the data will not be useful as you will loose a lot of the reference data. Still there is a way to solve this problem.

To ship data from Workspaces of All tenants to the Main Workspace of your tenant, you have to use **Microsoft Sentinel**. **Microsoft Sentinel is built on top of a Log Analytics workspace**. Microsoft Sentinel offers multiple-workspace capabilities that enable central monitoring, configuration, and management.

In your case you should use the Managed Security Service Provider (MSSP) Microsoft Sentinel service.  **The MSSP can use Azure Lighthouse to extend Microsoft Sentinel cross-workspace capabilities across tenants**. For more information check this [Work with incidents in many workspaces at once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/multiple-workspace-view) document. I would also suggest to read this [Extend Microsoft Sentinel across workspaces and tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/extend-sentinel-across-workspaces-tenants#managing-workspaces-across-tenants-using-azure-lighthouse) document from Microsoft for more information.

There is another approach to move logs from workspace of one tenant to another, but this approach is not so efficient as compared to the one mentioned above. You can use the Log Analytics Data export and send the events to EventHub of that tenant. Once the data is in an Event Hub, you can write a Logic App to process the data and write it to the Logic App in the new tenant. But Personally would recommend the first method not this one.